# strstr() in emacs lisp?

Tags: string, search, emacs

I want to search for a string in another one (basically what `strstr` does in C), and I don't find anything in the elisp manual.

Do I have to reimplement all that myself, or am I missing something obvious ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Or you could use regexps:

```
(string-match-p "foo" "barfoo")
3
```

or

```
(string-match "foo" "barbar")
nil
```

See [Regexp-Search](http://www.gnu.org/s/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Regexp-Search.html#Regexp-Search) for further information.

Answer (score 13):

Strings are sequences. And thus *search* will to the job:

```
(search "foo" "in foo-bar")
3
```

Comment: thanks to you both for your answers. I'm adding this comment to explain why I chose to mark @tuos' answer as accepted: on my linux box, `search` needs a `(require 'cl)`, so it's slightly less concise. And I'm not sure how case is treated, while it is explicit in the documentation for `string-match`. But thanks anyway.